# src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'xs:name'. It was detected that 'xs:name' is in namespace 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema'

Tags: java, xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I'm creating a Spring based SOAP web service, and I'm trying to return a custom list called AVAILABLE_PACKAGES which contains multiple PACKAGE_ITEM elements. Each one of these PACKAGE_ITEM elements is made by two strings,  PACKAGE_NAME and PACKAGE_PRICE.

I tried with multiple configurations, but I keep receiving an error on the line

```
<xs:element name="availablePackagesList" type="xs:AvailablePackagesList" />
```

The error reads as follows:

> Multiple annotations found at this line:
>
> - src-resolve: Cannot resolve the name 'xs:AvailablePackagesList' to a(n) 'type definition' component.
> - src-resolve.4.2: Error resolving component 'xs:AvailablePackagesList'. It was detected that
>   'xs:AvailablePackagesList' is in namespace
>   'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema', but components from this
>   namespace are not referenceable from schema document...

This is the code snippet of what I have on my .xsd file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http:/hello.com/queries"
    xmlns:tns="http:/hello.com/queries"
    elementFormDefault="qualified">

<!--GetSubscriberAvailablePackages -->

<xs:element
    name="MobileGetSubscriberAvailablePackagesRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="network" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="username" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="password" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="subscriberData" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="subscriberDataType" type="xs:string" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element
    name="MobileGetSubscriberAvailablePackagesResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="network" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="subscriberData" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="subscriberDataType" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="response" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="responseDetails" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="availablePackagesList"
                type="xs:AvailablePackagesList" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>


<xs:complexType name="AvailablePackagesList">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="AvaillablePackage"
            type="xs:AvaillablePackageItem" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>


<xs:complexType name="AvaillablePackageItem">
    <xs:attribute name="packageName" type="xs:integer"
        use="required" />
    <xs:attribute name="packagePrice" type="xs:integer"
        use="required" />
</xs:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To eliminate your immediate error and one subsequent error,

1. change `type="xs:AvailablePackagesList"` to `type="tns:AvailablePackagesList"`, and
2. change`type="xs:AvaillablePackageItem"` to `type="tns:AvaillablePackageItem"`

because both are in the `http:/yobitelecom.com/queries` namespace, not the `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema` namespace.